# Debugger in CUDA 5

Tags: cuda, nsight

Nvidia has released extended eclipse for CUDA 5. They have Nsight plugin for VS2010 also. In VS2010 we can stop program execution at breakpoint in kernel but how to achieve this functionality in eclipse on Linux? I don't see any nsight specific keys to stop execution. I tried changing perspective but it debugs as a normal C/C++ application. I'm using Tesla C2070, Intel Xeon 8 core machine with Linux.

Answer (score 2):

I'm from Nsight Eclipse Edition team.

Our goal is specifically for the application to be debugged as a normal C/C++ application. This means that you can set breakpoints, use "run to line", etc. regardless of whether you debug host or device code.

Basically, the process is quite standard for Eclipse:

1. Create a project (you can also import existing executable)
2. Click debug button
3. Debugger will run and by default will break in the main function. Note that no device code posted on the device so you will only see the host thread.
4. Set a breakpoint in the device code and hit resume (note that Breakpoints view toolbar also allows you setting breakpoint on any CUDA kernel launch)

Debugger will break when device code reaches the breakpoint. You can inspect your application state using visual debugger UI.

Comment: It's not working for me :( I can set break points in `cuda-gdb` but when I tried do the same in eclipse it doesn't stop. It stops only in main function, even if I have no device code at all.

Comment: @janisz there might be several reasons for that. Does your application run to completion successfully when ran in Nsight EE debugger? Can you break if you import CUDA samples? Do you run cuda-gdb from terminal emulator or console?

Comment: I was able to debug application in terminal, but when I set breakpoints in Eclipse I got ` "No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command."` in console log. I tried to change someting in configuration (random clicking) but nothing helps, application was build with proper flags. Finally following steps solve my problem: right click on project > Debug As > Local C/C++ Application. It switch me to debug mode and all breakpoins works. And now when I click on green bug it works too. I plug second card and I can even debbug kernel code :) Elipcse is not so easy as VS

Comment: @janisz It looks like you were trying to debug a release build.

Comment: Yes, but when I check output file it was not stripped and I can debug it. Probably eclipse use another filed to run debug, maybe some from temp. I don't know but I really happy that finally it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Couple things, and not sure which solved the issue. Drivers updated to latest ones with RC5.0, but I chose to run VNC server instead of native X server. Then the CUDA card(s) are dedicated to my apps and debugging, and it works like a charm, and now accessible from everywhere.

Comment: Is this really an answer? "I did a few very different things and now suddenly it works"? Perhaps this could have been a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Eugene,
I just installed Cuda 5, and I wasn't able to break in any kernel code.  It was a clean install of centos 5.5, with a fresh download of cuda-5, and i am running on a asus g71x laptop which has a gtx260m installed.

I thought maybe you cant run display and dedbug on one device still, so i switched to non-nv x display, but still had same issue, cant stop in the kernel code.

Comment: I think on Linux it is not possible to use debugging facility.

Comment: @TMB - this sort of reply should be submitted as a comment on Eugene's answer rather than as an answer in its own right. This way, we keep all answers relevant and SO is easier to read for other users. Cheers :)

Comment: Some common reasons the debugger failing to break in the device code are:
1. Same GPU is used for CUDA debugging and for OS UI. Nsight Eclipse Edition debugger requires a dedicated GPU.
2. CUDA API calls fail for some reason. Make sure you check return values from the CUDA API calls.
3. CUDA toolkit is not installed properly. One of the common problems is the wrong NVIDIA driver version installed on the system.

Comment: Can you try command-line cuda-gdb? Sometimes it provides a better diagnostics.

Comment: @username_4567 Please don't spread disinformation. CUDA debugging on Linux works just as well as Windows, if not better. Try cuda-gdb if you haven't already.
TMB: As Eugene said, please try out cuda-gdb. Nsight Eclipse uses that as the backend. It would help in isolating the problem. If cuda-gdb fails to hit a breakpoint too, we can absolve Nsight Eclipse of any blame.

Comment: @grimm I'm not spreading wrong info. You better mind your words. For me, it is not working because of first reason in Eugene's post.When i'm on Linux it doesn't work  but if I go to Windows it works fine. so I'm posting it on forum. So I don't think i'm spreading so called "misinformation". I asked question and in my comment I said "I think " so I expressed my opinion and didn't give verdict.

Comment: @username_4567 "I think on Linux it is not possible to use debugging facility." Right, what is that supposed to be, a blanket statement about the state of debugging on Linux? Qualify your statements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CUDA 5.0 RC1? It is available now. You can download and try it. And I have tried the Nsight in it, it works well for debugging.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

The 304.43 NVIDIA Driver does not let users other than root debug their CUDA application.

That problem is not present in any past or future public releases. The CUDA documentation recommends using only drivers listed in the CUDA DevZone. The 304.43 driver is not one of them.

That may or may not be the issue you are hitting. But I thought it was worth mentioning.