# Nsight 5.0 on MacPro lion 10.7.4

Tags: eclipse, cuda, nsight

I'm new to CUDA dev and I'm using NSight 5 on a MacPro.

I'm doing a very simple simulation with two particles (`ver1` and `ver2` here, which are two structs that have pointers to another type of structs – `links`)

The code compiled but seems to run into problem when reaches the end of this block, and never stepped into the `integrate_functor()`:

```
...    
thrust::device_vector<Vertex> d_vecGlobalVec(2);

d_vecGlobalVec[0] = ver1;
d_vecGlobalVec[1] = ver2;

thrust::for_each(
    d_vecGlobalVec.begin(),
    d_vecGlobalVec.end(),
    integrate_functor(deltaTime)
);
...
```

So my questions are:

1. In NSight, I can see the values of member variables of `ver1` and `ver2`; but right before the last line of the code in this block, when I expand the hierarchy of `d_vecGlobalVec`, I can see any of these values - the corresponding fields (e.g. of the first element in this vector) are just empty. Why is this the case? Obviously, `ver1` and `ver2` are on Host memo while the values in `d_vecGlobalVec` are on the device.
  2.

A member of the NSight team posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11868662/2041023).

So following that, in general, does it mean that I should be able to step in and out between host and device code, and be able to see host/device variables as if there is no barrier between them?

System:

NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB

Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4 (11E2620)

Comment: Ok, I just found out that apparently, it did go into the '__device__' annotated function

Comment: Ok, I just found out (by the good old 'print') that apparently, the program did go into the '__device__' annotated function, but the debug did not stop at the break point there


ChrisV @ NAVIDIA has a post addressing similar issue
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13692092

But my questions remain:

1. How can I get this to work in the NSight running on my mac, in particular, how to 'open a second IDE instance and attach its CPU debugger' with the standalone NSight on Mac OS 10

2. for some reason, the debugger always break at the first line of the main() function - will this impact on anything?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your device code is actually called. Check all return codes and confirm that device actually worked on the output. Sometimes thrust may run the code on host if it believes it is more effective.

I would really recommend updating to 10.8 - it has the latest drivers with the best support for NVIDIA GeForce 6xx series.

Also note that for optimum experience you need to have different GPUs for display and CUDA debugging - otherwise Mac OS X may interfere and kill the debugger.

Comment: Hi, Eugene, Thanks, but since the code terminated right there and it never stepped into my __device__ annotated function integrate_functor(), and I can't see exactly where given the lack of log info - how do I do what you suggested exactly? 

"Make sure your device code is actually called. Check all return codes and confirm that device actually worked on the output"

"

Comment: From the looks of it, your device code is never executed. There is multitude of possible reasons for that - most often it is wrong compiler settings (make sure you generate PTX and/or SASS for SM 3.0) or wrong launch configuration. I would recommend starting with simple CUDA C (sans Thrust) application (e.g. you can create bitreverse application using Nsight new CUDA C project wizard) to make sure CUDA toolkit is properly installed and can be used to develop applications.

Comment: Another option would be to send your source code to cudatools@nvidia.com (you may mention it is for Eugene) so we could reproduce/troubleshoot it locally.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, Eugene!

Yes, I have been running the Particle and NBody sample, and they all look like running fine. So I assume that the launch configuration and compiler settings are fine?

As you can see the comment I added to my original post, the biggest problem I have right now is that the debugger only stops at the host code not the device code. @ChrisV mentioned something about this problem, but I think it is still a bit different from my situation

Comment: Now, can you try using cuda-gdb to debug Particle or NBody and to confirm you can actually break in a device code? It is probable that you have some toolkit installation issue that GPU debugging.